# search dates with laravel not between query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to search for data with given dates and time (morning and evening). How can I find available dates from data with laravel query?
If i search dates **2019-06-10** to **2019-06-18**. It should only return id 3 and 4. In this query, it is returning id 1, 3 and 4. What's wrong with this query it is not checking from in between dates? I have date type column in the database for start and end date.
I want to check two conditions

1. Given dates should be not equal to date_from and date_to
2. Given dates are not between in these dates

Both conditions in same query. Hope you understand.

```
id  event_id   date_from    date_to   

1     1        2019-06-08   2019-06-12  
2     1        2019-06-14   2019-06-16  
3     2        2019-06-20   2019-06-25  
4     3        2019-07-26   2019-07-27
```

```php
$getEvents = Booking::where('category_id', '=', $categoryID)
                ->where('date_from', '!=', $startDate)
                ->where('date_to', '!=', $endDate)
                ->orWhere('date_from', '<', $startDate)
                ->orWhere('date_to', '>', $endDate)
                ->whereNotBetween('date_from', [$startDate,$endDate])
                ->whereNotBetween('date_to', [$startDate,$endDate])
                ->get();
```

Comment: dates 2019-06-10 to 2019-06-18, how id 4 its returned?, it should be only id 3 ?

Comment: Id 3 and 4 should return because these dates are no in that range... i have multiple halls i have to check in which hall these dates are available.. thats why it should return 3 and 4

Comment: The two orWhere could cause you problem, I think you should enclose them

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$endDate` will always be greater (or equal) than `$startDate`

```
$startDate = "2019-06-10";
$endDate = "2019-06-18";
```

> 2. Given dates are not between in these dates

```php
        ->whereDate('date_to', '<', $startDate)
        ->whereDate('date_from', '>', $endDate)
```

If given `$startDate` is  greater than db `'date_to'`, `$startDate` is not between `'date_to'` and `'date_from'`. Will retrieve records with `'date_to'` less than `"2019-06-10"`.

And when the given `'date_from'` is greater than `$endDate`, `$endDate` is not between `'date_to'` and `'date_from'`. Will retrieve records with `'date_from'` greater than `"2019-06-18"`.

> 1. Given dates should be not equal to date_from and date_to

This is not needed since in the query of point 2, we use > and <, which will not take into account equals.

```php
    //->where('date_from', '<>', $startDate)->where('date_from', '<>', $endDate)
    //->where('date_to', '<>', $startDate)->where('date_to', '<>', $endDate)
```

Just:

```php
$getEvents = Booking::where('category_id', '=', $categoryID)
            ->whereDate('date_to', '<', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('date_from', '>', $endDate)
            ->get();
```

Comment: this is also not working ... I want to check two conditions 1) Given dates should be not equal to date_from and date_to 2) Given dates are not between in these dates both conditions in same query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DB::table('table_name')
    ->whereNotBetween('date', [star_date, end_date])    
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel 5

```
$getEvents = Booking::where('category_id', '=', $categoryID)
                ->where('date_from', '<', $startDate)
                ->where('date_to', '>', $endDate)
                ->get();
```